# My screen randomly turns off

Tags: screen, 23.04

I am using Ubuntu 23.04 with a dual monitor set up, and just today my screens have started to randomly turn off. I can move my mouse and the screens come back on again. Its like my screens go to sleep at arbitrary time intervals. Sometimes it can happen as little as 5 seconds after I have stopped activity, other times it can be as much as 10 minutes. Here are my power save settings:

[image]

I can't see any clues in /var/log/syslog.